# How do I rename a file with Amazon's s3api?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rename

I'm using Amazon's s3api interface to attempt to rename a file I have already uploaded to a bucket (done in a bash script).  I wanted to run the command

```
aws s3api --recursive mv s3://$bucket_name/$file_name s3://$bucket_name/$file_name.$last_modified_file_date
```

but evidently something has changed because the above dies with the error

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

abort-multipart-upload                   | complete-multipart-upload               
copy-object                              | create-bucket                           
create-multipart-upload                  | delete-bucket
```

How can I rename a file that exists in my bucket?

Comment: The 'mv' subcommand is for 'aws s3', not for 'aws s3api'.

Comment: What's the command for s3api?

Comment: You know that both 'aws s3' and 'aws s3api' target the S3 service, yes? They just expose different sets of S3 function. The awscli has in-built help, for example: aws s3api help. You'll see that it doesn't have an equivalent move subcommand, so you should use 'aws s3 mv' or you can emulate it with s3api by calling copy-object followed by delete-object.

Comment: I don't think you can use `--recursive` if you are _renaming_ files. `aws s3 mv --recursive` will probably work for _moving_ objects to a new path, but I don't see how it would work for _renaming_ multiple objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly rename a file in s3, your only option is to use the 'mv' command and use a new name for the destination key:

```
aws s3 --recursive mv s3://<bucket>/<old_key> s3://<bucket>/<new_key>
```

Comment: But I am using the "mv" command.  Am I missing something?  See my first coded line?

Comment: You are calling "s3api", when you should be calling just "s3"

Comment: Some time has passed, but feel free to select the answer so that this question can be marked as complete, it will benefit us both as well as anyone else stumbling across this question